# What will happened to server request if client suddenly close it's connection

Tags: asp.net, iis

If I have a page that takes some amount of time to process, and suddenly the client closes it's connection (network disconnect, browser closed, etc), what will happened to the processing operation on the server side? Is it get canceled automatically or it continues to process, and then stop right before rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It continues processing until something notices that the client has disconnected and calls Response.End(). You can check yourself with the [Response.IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property.